# Install phpsh on Windows

Tags: php, phpsh

Has anyone had success installing phpsh on Windows?

I have Php 5.2 and Python 2.7 on my Windows 7 machine.  When I try to run setup.py, I get a `NameError: name '__init__' is not defined`. I found someone had forked the project [here](https://github.com/jefflafay/phpsh), but I ran into the same error.

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Please comment if you're going to downvote. I'd like to know what to do better.

Comment: I need to know a simple solution to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for phpsh on Windows is to run [CoLinux](http://www.colinux.org/). Then you have a full Linux and Windows running together without having to run a virtual machine. The only other choice is to run a virtual machine with Linux, but if you system is slow this would not be fun.